# Put variable into json text body

Tags: java, json

is that any idea on putting variable into json text body and POST it out? Here is my text body

```
final String POST_PARAMS = "{\n" + "\"company\": 101,\r\n" +
   "    \"product\": 101,\r\n" +
    "    \"condition\": \"Test Title\",\r\n" +
    "    \"delivery_time\": \"Test Body\``"" + "\n}";
```

Comment: Concatenate it? Or use a real JSON builder?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [org.json.JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Example:

```
myString = new JSONObject()
         .put("JSON", "Hello, World!").toString();

produces the string {"JSON": "Hello, World"}
```

Comment: can i replace "hello,world!" with my variable? for example, myString = new JSONObject()
         .put("JSON", myString1).toString();

Comment: Obiouvsly you can